# Create a Dropdown to show more Views in Android

Tags: android, layout, android-custom-view, dropdownbox

I am trying to code a layout, but I do not know well how to approach it.

Initially I have the following:

[image]

When the user click in this View, I need to show:

[image]

I thought I will need a `Spinner`, but the content that is shown when the user click is not a list but a set of `Views` (In this case, it will be a `LinearLayout` with a `Spinner` and a `EditText`).

I am a little lost, what would be the best approach to achieve this?

Do I need to implement a CustomView?

Sorry if it is a dummy question, but I can figure out how to code this `Layout`.

Comment: Create a customview and supply that layout to arrayadapter of the spinner your attaching..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best approach would be to make a LinearLayout in wich you can place you Spinner and your Search EditText and set this LinearLayout ViewGroup `setVisible(View.INVISIBLE)`.

Then when you click on the "registra alimento" View set the LinearLayout below to `setVisible(View.VISIBLE)`

To fade it in:

```
Animation in = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, android.R.anim.fade_in);
viewToAnimate.startAnimation(in);
viewToAnimate.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: The `Registrar Alimento` View would be a TextView with a custom Style, and when the user clicks it I could set the LinearLayout to visible and add it a Animation?

Comment: You can use a custom TextView and let it implement OnClickListener or use a Default one and setOnClickListener(...)

Comment: Thanks, I will try and let you know.

Answer (score 1):

Take one Linear layout add  Textview of Registrar alimento than set linear onClickListener with visibility of Spinner and edittext.(Also maintain flag for visible invisible )